# Boolean values returned in different format from PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

We have 2 servers having the same code on both. On one of them interrogation on a table returns t/f for boolean true/false and on the other it returns 0/1. Do you have any idea why this happens? Maybe a yii setting or a server setting?

Comment: Displaying (and formatting) of the database values is done by your SQL *client*. So you should check for any differences in the tool you are using.

Comment: have you tested your query with psql on a both servers? Do results differ?

Comment: Yes. I have tested. on one the returned array contains 'f' where false and on the other it contains null where false. For true it contains 't' on first server and 1 on second.

Comment: Are both servers running PostgreSQL?  Or is one running MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

first some background.

Many RDBMS's do not support a bool type and so people use very small int fields for this purpose.  PostgreSQL supports a bool type with three values:  `true`, `false`, or `null` (or unknown).

It isn't 100% clear from the question of both servers are PostgreSQL.  If one is PostgreSQL and one is not, one would expect this sort of behavior so this is the first thing to note.  However even if both are PostgreSQL, it wouldn't be unheard of for a db designer to design one set of tables to use smallints or bits, and then change to a bool later.

If both systems are PostgreSQL, the only thing that can cause this in psql is different table designs.  Take a look at `\d tablename` and check to see if one is set up to use bool and another is set up to use a bit or integer type.